# How to set FV-5 as my default camera on XtreStoLite 3.1.1

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-6, default-applications

I just installed XtreStoLite 3.1.1 on my G-920T (Galaxy S6 with T-Mobile) and then installed Camera FV-5. How do I make that my default camera? In other words, when I double-press the home button, how do I make FV-5 the camera that opens instead of the default camera?

Comment: @beeshyams The OS is named in the question's subject. I was actually able to set FV-5 as the default camera app using the normal method. However, double pressing the home button still launches the out-of-the-box camera app, for some reason. Also, App Picker Classic seems to want to become my new launcher, so I don't think that will work.

Comment: @beeshyams Hey! How did you know I have Titanium Backup? :) Okay. I tried that. What happened is that double pressing the home button merely does the same thing as single pressing it—it takes you to the home screen. I verified that the double-press feature is still enabled. I also turned it off and then back on. Same thing. Good idea, though!

Comment: @beeshyams Actually, I just flashed XtreStoLite 3.2 since posting this question and last night I re-flashed Aroma, so it doesn't seem like that will make any difference, unfortunately. I also posted the question on XDA, but no one replied. I'll go back and harass them some more. :) I sure appreciate your time!